# Daisy-chaining two displays

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, vga, daisychaining

I have a laptop with a card sufficient for multiple monitor setup. Then I have two displays:

Samsung Syncmaster NC240 (used for a virtual desktop solution originally)
generic Dell display

Can I somehow plug them serially (I learnt this is called daisy-chaining) this way?

1. From laptop to VGA-in on the NC240
2. From VGA-out on the NC240 to the VGA-in on the Dell?

I actually succeeded in this endeavour on 50 %:

The NC240 works as the secondary display for the laptop (both extended and duplicate) if I switch the source (as from PC, not from network) but it does not feed the picture further into the Dell monitor, it feeds always the VDI stuff.

Comment: VGA is not designed to daisy-chain multiple monitors together.  (Thunderbolt can.) for VGA, an active device is needed to split (or duplicate) a VGA signal for multiple destinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never heard of VGA daisy chaining. It's never existed as far as I know, and I'd be surprised if it worked.

What I suspect here is a misunderstanding of how/why those ports are there.

You can *either* use the VGA in, for using the Syncmaster as a traditional monitor *or* use a VDI using the built in VDI thin client, with DVI or VGA for a second monitor

Annoyingly, the [monitor manual](https://images10.newegg.com/User-Manual/User_Manual_24-001-412.pdf) is not very clear about it - saying

> Connect to the [DVI OUT], [RGB OUT] port to display the same picture on another monitor such as the projector.
>   (For presentation purposes)

So, you should at least get a mirrored output but no more.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that the VGA-out is there for secondary monitor for the VDI. I just hoped I could work around the fact that we are missing some connectors and it will take weeks to get through the corporate bureaucracy to get them using a more exotic solution, but what can you do...